# AWS CloudFormation: Route table not populating

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

AWS CloudFormation: I have an existing VPC with public subnet and it has a an associated Route Table already.

I have written a CloudFormation template for attaching VPN gateway route propagation to public route table.

The issue is how to reference public route table from VPC id?

Adding following in parameters is not populating any route table to select:

```
  PubRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable::id
    Description: PublicRoute table Id for Public Subnet
```

Also, I did get any code to refer back from VPC id to Route Table.

Comment: What do you mean by "code to refer back from VPC id to Route Table"?

Answer (score 1):

[Parameters - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) does not list `RouteTable` as an allowable type for parameters.

Therefore, you will need to define it as `Type: String` and the user must provide the Route Table ID rather than selecting it from a list.

Comment: is there any way to refer from vpc id to route table id in cloudformation?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Every Route Table is associated with a VPC, and a VPC can have many Route tables. Could you please explain what you are wanting to achieve, or what you are wanting to build in the CloudFormation template?